# Find recent and upcoming dates

Tags: php

I have a two-dimensional array containing events and dates:

```
$events = array(
    array('event' => 'event1', 'date' => '2016-05-05'),
    array('event' => 'event2', 'date' => '2016-05-08'),
    array('event' => 'event3', 'date' => '2016-05-08'),
    array('event' => 'event4', 'date' => '2016-05-10'),
    array('event' => 'event5', 'date' => '2016-05-10'),
    array('event' => 'event6', 'date' => '2016-05-11'),
    array('event' => 'event7', 'date' => '2016-05-11'),
    array('event' => 'event8', 'date' => '2016-05-13')
};
```

Let's say today is `2016-05-10` and I want to create 3 new arrays:

> $recent - all events happened on the previous available day
>   $today - all events today
>   $upcoming - all events happening on the next available day

`$today` is easy:

```
$today = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($events); ++$i) {
    if($events[$i]['date'] == date("Y-m-d") {
        array_push($today, $events[$i]['event']);
    }
}
```

So, I will need `$recent` to contain `event2` and `event3`, and `$upcoming` to contain `event6` and `event7`.

The question is how to find the `recent` and the `upcoming` ones.

***Clarification:**
I don't want all the events in `$recent` happened before today, but the events happened on the previous available day. So in this case only events happened on `2016-05-08`

Comment: check the date is greater than today or less than today...

Comment: @FrayneKonok No, it's not enough. I need to have in recent only those happened on `2016-05-08`. push_array -> array_push

Comment: Check the answer, I update as per your requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Take all dates from source array
$dates = array_unique(array_map(function ($i) { return strtotime($i); } , array_column($events, 'date')));
sort($dates);
$today = strtotime('midnight');
// find previouse date. It will be 1970-1-1 if not present in array
$prev = @max(array_filter($dates, function($i) use($today) { return $i < $today; }));
// find туче date. It will be 1970-1-1 if not present in array
$next = @min(array_filter($dates, function($i) use($today) { return $i > $today; }));

$prev = date('Y-m-d', $prev);
$next = date('Y-m-d', $next);

// fill arrays
$recent = array();
$upcoming = array();
$today = array();

for($i = 0; $i < count($events); ++$i) {
    if($events[$i]['date'] == date('Y-m-d')) {
        array_push($today, $events[$i]['event']);
    }
    if($events[$i]['date'] == $prev) {
        array_push($recent, $events[$i]['event']);
    }
    if($events[$i]['date'] == $next) {
        array_push($upcoming , $events[$i]['event']);
    } 
}
```

Comment: @FrayneKonok Thank you

Comment: Excellent answer @splash58 . Thanks you.

Comment: Even a cat likes a kind word :))

Answer (score 1):

Try with creating three (3) blank array, check the date is greater or less than today or not and push into array according to conditions.

```
$today = array();
$upcoming = array();
$recent = array();  

$thisDay = date("Y-m-d");
$count = count($events);
$max = max(array_column($events, 'date'));
$min = min(array_column($events, 'date'));

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
    if($events[$i]['date'] > $thisDay){
        $max = ($max > $events[$i]['date']) ? $events[$i]['date'] : $max;
        array_push($upcoming, $events[$i]['event']);
        array_push($upcoming_dates, $events[$i]['date']);   
    }
    elseif($events[$i]['date'] < $thisDay){
        $min = ($min < $events[$i]['date']) ? $events[$i]['date'] : $min;
        array_push($recent, $events[$i]['event']);
        array_push($recent_dates, $events[$i]['date']);
    }
    else
        array_push($today, $events[$i]['event']);
}

foreach($recent_dates as $key => $value){
    if($value != $min)
        unset($recent[$key]);
}

foreach($upcoming_dates as $key => $value){
    if($value != $max)
        unset($upcoming[$key]);
}

echo '<pre>';   
print_r($today);
print_r($upcoming);
print_r($recent);
```

**Result**

Today:

```
Array
(
    [0] => event4
    [1] => event5
)
```

Upcoming:

```
Array
(
    [0] => event6
    [1] => event7
)
```

Recent:

```
Array
(
    [1] => event2
    [2] => event3
)
```

> Note: You use `push_array` which is not any library function in PHP. For Re-index of recent and upcoming you can use `array_values`.

Comment: Nope, you have everything in `recent`, but I need events happened only on the previous day. Like I mentioned in my Q: "So, I will need $recent to contain event2 and event3..." So event1 should not be in it for sure.

Comment: Then leave `$recent` empty.

Comment: Previous day means the day for the last event before today.

Comment: if today is `10 May 2016`, if there are no dates with `11 May 2016` or `9 May 2016` then empty?? Right?

Comment: No, but mate please read my Q. I exactly described my expected result. If today is `2016-05-10` and there is no date `2016-05-09` then add event from `2016-05-08`.

Comment: One more query: Is recent and upcoming is array?? Or just a single value.

Comment: Array. I need all the events happening on that date.

Comment: @fishmong3r, Done updating question.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution should be

```
$recent = array();
$upcoming = array();
$today = array();
$all_dates = array();

foreach ($events as $event):
array_push($all_dates, $event['date']);
endforeach;

if ($key = array_search('2016-05-10', $all_dates)) {
  $prev_date = $all_dates[$key - 1];
}
for ($i = 0; $i < count($all_dates); $i++) {
if ($all_dates[$i] > $all_dates[$key]) {
    $next_date = $all_dates[$i + 1];
    break;
 }
}

for ($i = 0; $i < count($events); ++$i) {
if ($events[$i]['date'] == date('Y-m-d')) {
    array_push($today, $events[$i]['event']);
}
if ($events[$i]['date'] == $prev_date) {
    array_push($recent, $events[$i]['event']);
}
if ($events[$i]['date'] == $next_date) {
    array_push($upcoming, $events[$i]['event']);
 }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($upcoming);
print_r($today);
print_r($recent);
```

Output will be

```
Array
(
[0] => event6
[1] => event7
)

Array
(
[0] => event4
[1] => event5
)

Array
(
[0] => event2
[1] => event3
)
```